# xtightvncviewer showing a gray screen

Tags: vnc

This is my ~/.vnc/xstartup file

```
#!/bin/sh
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```

While connecting from another system where xtightvncviewer is installed, I get only a gray screen.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the following lines to ~/.vnc/xstartup, killed the session and started it again.

Instead of the gray window, I get a brand new session of the remote machine.

```
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

Comment: And it what? Is this the solution or were you trying to add more information to your question?

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't complete the answer. I have now edited it and completed.

Comment: @flipper, could you post your entire `xstartup` file please?

Comment: @ZionPerez I no longer use the same system. Therefore I don't have the ~/.vnc/xstartup in question.